# Change Android Camera flashlight color

Tags: android, flashlight

I have a simple app which turns on/off the flash light, but curious if there are any hue settings I can play around with to change the color of the light.

This is my code to turn on the flashlight;

```
private void turnOnFlash() {
    if (!isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
        playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;

        // changing button/switch image
        toggleButtonImage();
    }

}
```

Comment: The light color can't be changed..

Answer (score 0):

No the flash is just effectively a light bulb. You can change the color of most notification leds if you just want color though.